# Postgres array lookup multiple values in where clause

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, where-clause

I have below table with data

```
create table stud(key int, person text, subject_id int[]);

insert into stud select 1,'Alex',array[2,7,9];
insert into stud select 2,'Peter',array[4,9,12];
insert into stud select 3,'Tokaver',array[8];
insert into stud select 4,'Machel',array[11,15];
```

Table looks

[image]

I can filter single subject_id in where like

```
select * from stud where 9=any(subject_id)
```

How can we filter more than one subject_id in where clause like

```
select * from stud where (8,9) in any(subject_id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=753caef8439daa4069868880531da600)

You can use the overlap operator `&&` for arrays:

```
select * from stud 
where array[8,9] && subject_id
```